# On diagonalizations over complexity classes

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity

I am looking for the following PhD thesis, but could not find it, and all my attempts for finding it failed.

I am wondering if there is a way to get it:

On diagonalizations over complexity classes

By: Hans Fleischhack

Comment: Did you try to contact the author? https://uol.de/parsys/kontakte/ehemalige/fleischhack

Comment: I emailed, but didn't get any replies.

Comment: I even emailed the university for the file, but they just had hard copy, not the file.